# ValidationError assertion not working when pytest shows the same values

Tags: python, unit-testing, validationerror, python-jsonschema

I'm writing a unit test whereby I want to assert that the error I get:

```
<ValidationError: "'a list' is not of type 'array'">
```

is equal too

```
assert ValidationError(message="'a list' is not of type 'array'")
```

I'm using a simple assertion:

```
assert actual == expected
```

When I run `pytest` I get the following error:

```
 assert <ValidationError: "'a list' is not of type 'array'"> == <ValidationError: "'a list' is not of type 'array'">
```

The validation error comes from jsonschema

```
from jsonschema import ValidationError
```

Even though they are identical, the assertion still fails. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

Normally I would structure this using `pytest.raises`

```
def test_validation_error():
    with pytest.raises(ValidationError, match="'a list' is not of type 'array'"):
        # whatever you are doing to raise the error
        assert ValidationError(message="'a list' is not of type 'array'")
```

Answer (score 2):

This exception doesn't seem to have `__eq__` method defined, so it is being compared using ids - and since those are 2 different objects, they have different ids. Just like this code will throw an error, because Python doesn't really know how 2 different TypeErrors should be compared.

```
assert TypeError('a') == TypeError('a')
```

If you check [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/assert.html), suggested way to handle expected exceptions looks like this:

```
def test_zero_division():
    with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
        1 / 0
```